# Yii2 передать переменную с одного виджета в другой?

Tags: yii2, виджет

Есть два виджета(пример из доков)

Первый

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;

    class HelloWidget extends Widget
    {
        public $message;

        public function init()
        {
            parent::init();
            if ($this->message === null) {
                $this->message = 'Hello World';
            }
        }

        public function run()
        {
            return Html::encode($this->message);
        }
    }
```

И второй

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class WorldWidget extends Widget
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->message // получить переменную виджета HelloWidget 
    }
}
```

Виджеты вызываются один за другим в одном представлении, т.е.

```
HelloWidget::widget(['message' => 'Good morning'])
WorldWidget::widget()
```

Возможно ли получить значение переменной $message виджета HelloWidget в виджете WorldWidget ? Пробую так

```
\Yii::$app->view->message
```

Получаю

> Getting unknown property: yii\web\View::message

Comment: Нашел http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-view.html#$params-detail
Правда не знаю насколько правильно так делать вообще, как думаете ?

Comment: Скажите, зачем вам получать переменную $message из виджета _HelloWidget_? Не понятна суть проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, что в рамках данного вопроса просто схематично описана суть более сложной задачи.

Не есть хорошо, передавать что либо из одного виджета в другой. Так как виджеты, следуя идеологии, это отдельная программная единица.

Но если уж такая задача встала, то мной решалась бы так:

```
Hello Widget
public function run()
{
    \Yii::$app->params['some_value'] => $this->message;
    return Html::encode($this->message);
}

WorldWidget
$value = \Yii::$app->params['some_value'];
```

Возможно, это не самый лучший вариант но в рамках неординарности задачи (видимо это очень важный параметр нужно передать), может подойти.